# How to show camera on android gallery?

Tags: android

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

When I use these line for select image from my device gallery then by default cancel button is display on title bar of my device gallery screen. On the place of cancel button I want that display Camera Image Please Can any one suggested me that how to show camera

Answer (score 1):

```
frmcamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);

                }
            });
            frmalbumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent int_album = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    int_album.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(int_album, 2);

                }
            });




            @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

        } else if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            File file = new File(picturePath);
            Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(file);
            imgview.setImageBitmap(bmpp);


        }
    }



    public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: When i use this code then i select image from gallery and capture image using camera but not capture image using camera from gallery

Comment: Yes I know but i want that when i go on gallery screen for select image then i could capture image on gallery screen

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Camera applications layout are independent of the other application's . It will changed according to the devices as well as the API. You can not change the design of the layout of the default camera application.

If you want then you can create your own layout and open the camera on your own.

Comment: If i open gallery of my device using these lines so it is also possible that i can set camera on gallery? is it possible ?

Comment: No its not possible. You need to show the camera using the Canvas and surfaceholder.

Comment: please check this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/jzRIk.png Where is the cancel button I want to set the camera

Comment: Where do you want to set cancel in your camera ?

Comment: When i use these lines Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(i, 2);  then by default http://i.stack.imgur.com/jzRIk.png on this screen cancel button is display but i want set the camera on the place of cancel button